# PHP versions Difference (Manually Installation only)

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-yosemite, httpd.conf

Pre-installed Php & Apache on OS X Yosemite of Mac Book Pro.
I had manually updated the Php on my OSX with Php5.6.9.tar downloaded from official site. and then now the Terminal runs Php version is different to the Safari Browser.
How to make the browser runs same(latest) version to the terminal shown?

Php Details on Safari Browser:

> - PHP Version 5.5.20
>
>   - Configuration Path: /etc
>   - Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
>   - Additional .ini files: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
>   - Server Root: /usr
>   - Document Root: /Users/USER_ACCOUNT/Documents/htdocs
>   - Contest Document Root: /Users/USER_ACCOUNT/Documents/htdocs

Php Details on Terminal:

> - Php Version 5.6.9
>
>   - CLI Binary: /usr/local/bin/
>   - CLI man page: /usr/local/php/man/man1/
>   - CGI Binary: /usr/local/bin/
>   - CGI man page: /usr/local/php/man/man1/
>   - Build environment: /usr/local/lib/php/build/
>   - Header Files: /usr/local/include/php/
>   - Helper Programs: /usr/local/bin
>   - Man Pages: /usr/local/php/man/man1/
>   - PEAR Environment: /usr/local/lib/php/

Comment: You might want to turn this into an actual question...

Comment: "Php Version 5.9.9" I very much doubt that.

Comment: "PHP v5.9.9"... Whoa! Are you from the future?

Comment: Make your life easier, use Xampp for Mac https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html

Comment: Sorry... edited.. It's 5.6.9.. I am very sleepy right now, because I am looking the solution more than 36hrs... ='<
I wish the solution is Manually Installation.. I don't want Package Installation or 3rd Party..

Comment: Save yourself some grief and use Homebrew.

Comment: Pls answer and teaching with Manually Installation only. Appreciated very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Server API` value in the browser's phpinfo() output. If it is an `Apache 2.0 Handler`, probably, you haven't upgraded `mod_php`.

Take `libphp5.so` from PHP 5.6, rename it to `/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp56.so` and change it's path in Apache's `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp56.so
```

Then restart Apache

Comment: Well... There are no latest version modules in the php5.6.9 folder.